# Rayleigh test in R

Tags: r, statistics, circular-dependency

I'm trying to do a Rayleigh test for circular uniformity. Everything runs, but do I have an error in my setup? I'm calculating distance in semitones (musical unit) but am using clock/hour units since both are base 12.

```
library(circular)
> semitone_dist_y3 = c(-5, -5, -4, -4, -3, -2, -2,-2,-2,-2,-2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2,2,2,3, 4, 5, 5, 5)
> semitone_dist_y3 = circular(semitone_dist_y3, units = "hours", template = "clock12", modulo = "2pi")
> rayleigh.test(semitone_dist_y3)

       Rayleigh Test of Uniformity 
       General Unimodal Alternative 

Test Statistic:  0.6984 
P-value:  0
```

The data is fairly close to randomly distributed, so I don't think it's correct that I keep getting p-values of 0 for sets like this and values < .05 for sets with actual random distribution. Just starting to learn R for this project, so am sure I'm making some kind of careless mistake.